# How can I use C++ with Objective-C in XCode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I want to use/reuse C++ object with Objective-C.
I have a hello.h that has the class definition, and hello.cpp for class implementation.

```
class Hello
{ int getX() ... };
```

And I use this class in Objective-C function.

```
#include "hello.h"
...
- (IBAction) adderTwo:(id)sender
{
    Hello *hi = new Hello();            
    int value = hi->getX();
    NSLog(@"Hello %d", value);
    [textField setIntValue:value];
```

When I compile the code in Xcode, I get this error message.

```
class Hello *XXXXX
Users/smcho/Desktop/cocoa/adderTwo/hello.h:9:0
/Users/smcho/Desktop/cocoa/adderTwo/hello.h:9: 
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Hello'
```

What went wrong?

Comment: May this helps as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546879/1306012 or http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure you compile that file as "Objective-C++".

The simplest way is to rename it as ***.mm**.

If you don't want to rename the *.m file,

1. Select your file.
2. Open the File Info dialog (Cmd+I)
3. In File Type, select "sourcecode.cpp.objcpp"

Comment: Thank you man!! You helped me discover similar problem which took my two crazy days.

Comment: Now Xcode displays a more understandable suggestion Objectice-C++ Source

Answer (score 10):

Rename the Objective-C file from `filename.m` to `filename.mm` to make it compile as Objective-C++.