# How to use C++ libs in Objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, libraries

Objective-C - is a language belonging to C group languages.

In that case, I can use any `C++` libraries in my iOS project, am I right?

How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: the `Objective-C` is a thin layer above the `ANSI C`, the `C++` is on different branch... but according to your logic the `C#` code should run in `Xcode` because there a letter `C` in its name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you wish to integrate the source code of the library into your application, then your question is indeed a duplicate of [How can I use C++ with Objective-C in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683101/how-can-i-use-c-with-objective-c-in-xcode) as mentionned by [tilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184245/tilo)
- If you wish to use the built library (for instance a `.so` file), you need to:

  1. Create your Xcode project
  2. Include the library in your resources
  3. Add the headers to your project
  4. Load the library at runtime (see code below)

.

```
    // 1. Load library
    void *lib = dlopen("path/to/you/lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    // 2. Handle errors (load failed)
    if (!lib) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlopen(): %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // 3. Get lib functions addresses
    any_library_function = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "any_library_function");

    // 4. Use the functions
    any_library_function(…);
```

***Note:*** You may need to rename the source file in which you use that code from `.m` to `.mm`. Best is to do that directly in Xcode after the file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Either your C++ library exposes bindings with C linkage that you can use directly in Objective-C, or you can use Objective-C++ to access the C++ bindings.