# Can I have Swift, Objective-C, C and C++ files in the same Xcode project?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, swift, bridging-header

Can all 4 languages be used in the same project at all, and if so how?

There are *similar* questions in the flavor: [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files) to which the accepted answer is *no*.

Using `Bridging Header` adequately, `.h` that do not contain `C++` statements, `Objective-C` wrappers when `.h` do contain `C++`, `.mm` files to do the actual wrapping of `C++` classes, and `.swift`, can the 4 languages (5 if you include `Objective-C++`) build and link into a single executable?

---

[objective-c++](/questions/tagged/objective-c%2b%2b)[xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode)

Comment: Yes. You only need wrap `C++` into `C` or `Objective-C` to use in `Swift`.

Comment: Indeed, I have a project that does exactly that. C++ for the thrust of the abstract cross-platform model stuff with some C parts underneath; Objective-C to wrap the C++ classes for Swift purposes, Swift to bind all that to a subclass of `NSDocument`, with some custom views that interrogate the C stuff.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

## YES.

*You can mix `Swift`, `C`, `C++`, `Objective-C` & `Objective-C++` files in the same Xcode project.*

## C

```c
// Declaration: C.h
#ifndef C_h
#define C_h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void hello_c(const char * name);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* C_h */

// Definition: C.c
#include "C.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void hello_c(const char * name) {
    printf("Hello %s in C\n", name);
}
```

## C++

```cpp
// Declaration: CPP.hpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
class CPP {
public:
    void hello_cpp(const std::string& name);
};

// Definition: CPP.cpp
#include "CPP.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void CPP::hello_cpp(const std::string& name) {
    cout << "Hello " << name << " in C++" << endl;
}
```

## Objective-C wrapper for C++

```m
// Declaration: CPP-Wrapper.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface CPP_Wrapper : NSObject
- (void)hello_cpp_wrapped:(NSString *)name;
@end

// Definition: CPP-Wrapper.mm
#import "CPP-Wrapper.h"
#include "CPP.hpp"
@implementation CPP_Wrapper
- (void)hello_cpp_wrapped:(NSString *)name {
    CPP cpp;
    cpp.hello_cpp([name cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
@end
```

## Objective-C

```m
// Declaration: Objective-C.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Objective_C : NSObject
- (void)hello_objectiveC:(NSString *)name;
@end

// Definition: Objective-C.m
#import "Objective-C.h"
@implementation Objective_C
- (void)hello_objectiveC:(NSString*)name {
    printf("Hello %s in Objective-C\n", [name cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
@end
```

## Objective-C++

```mm
// Declaration: Objective-CPP.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Objective_CPP : NSObject
- (void)hello_objectiveCpp:(NSString *)name;
@end

// Definition: Objective-CPP.mm
#include <iostream>
#import "Objective-CPP.h"
using namespace std;
@implementation Objective_CPP
- (void)hello_objectiveCpp:(NSString *)name {
    cout << "Hello " << [name cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] << " in Objective-C++\n";
}
@end
```

## Swift

```swift
// Declaration & definition: Swift.swift
func hello_swift(_ name: String) {
    print("Hello \(name) in Swift")
}
```

## Bridging-Header.h

*Cannot import `CPP.hpp` header file, not because of it's naming convention, but because it contains the `class` keyword.*

```m
#import "C.h"
#import "CPP-Wrapper.h"
#import "Objective-C.h"
#import "Objective-CPP.h"
```

## Invocation from Swift

```swift
// Invoke C
hello_c("World".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))

// Can't Invoke C++ without a wrapper
// CPP().hello_cpp("World".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
// Invoke C++ through Objective-C
CPP_Wrapper().hello_cpp_wrapped("World")

// Invoke Objective-C
Objective_C().hello_objectiveC("World")

// Invoke Objective-C++
Objective_CPP().hello_objectiveCpp("World")

// Invoke Swift
Swift().hello_swift("World")
```

## .h (Headers)

(See *item 3* in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32554229/218152))

> .h: this is the tricky part, since they are ambiguously used for all flavors of C, ++ or not, Objective or not. When a .h does not contain a single C++ keyword, like class, it can be added to the ...Bridging-Header.h, and will expose whatever function the corresponding .c or .cpp functionalities it declares. Otherwise, that header must be wrapped in either a pure C or Objective-C API.

### Output

```
Hello World in C
Hello World in C++
Hello World in Objective-C
Hello World in Objective-C++
Hello World in Swift
```

---

**Comments**

*[Cy-4AH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934750/cy-4ah)*:

Yes. You only need wrap `C++` into `C` or `Objective-C` to use in `Swift`.

*[Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427332/tommy)*

Indeed, I have a project that does exactly that. `C++` for the thrust of the abstract cross-platform model stuff with some `C` parts underneath; `Objective-C` to wrap the `C++` classes for `Swift` purposes, `Swift` to bind all that to a subclass of `NSDocument`, with some custom views that interrogate the `C` stuff.

*[MaddTheSane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1975001/maddthesane)*

Added the `extern "C"` wrapper as per your excellent suggestion. To invoke the **C** method `void hello_c(const char * name)` from **C++** method `hello_cpp(const std::string& name)`, add `#include "C.h"` and call `hello_c(name.c_str());`.

*[Keith Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135952/keith-adler)*

The *new [SO-32541268](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes#SO-32541268)*: Now with parameters!

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32541268) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes#SO-32541268).

Comment: +1 - amazing answer, but real shame that the simple C++ method does not take a pointer or reference to another C++ object as a parameter - that's what's doing my head in.

Comment: Note that you may need to wrap C functions in `extern "C" { }` if you include and call them in C++ source code. This also means you can have a function that is C compliant implemented in C++ and that is called in Swift.

Comment: Awesome! Is there a performance penalty for having all these wrapper functions?

Comment: Credit to the critics who have suggested edits and enhancements.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect it's absolutely great example, but I think if you include <vector> or <iostream> in .h file of objective c++ wrapper it will is not working for me

Comment: @SwiftArchitect does this still work?  `#include <string>` produces the following error `'string' file not found` in CPP.hpp.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I see what my problem was. I named `CPP-Wrapper` with .m instead of .mm  You may want to change your  'Objective-C wrapper for C++' title to 'Objective-C++ wrapper for C++'.  Even though you have the filename in the comments ending in .mm, if someone (like I did) creates a .m  then `#include <string>` produces the following error `'string' file not found` in CPP.hpp.  Thanks for this great resource. :-)

Comment: Correct. Watch out for `.h`, `.c.`, `.hpp`, `.cpp`, `m`, `.mm` & `.swift`.

Comment: can someone provide an example how to call from .cpp to swift or objective c?

Comment: Today's idiom for Invoke C from Swift is apparently:
hello_c(("World" as NSString).cString(using: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

Comment: Elaborate information is here: https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/

Comment: As for the ```'string' file not found``` error, Swift code interoperates with C and Objective-C APIs by default. You must enable interoperability with C++ if you want to use C++ APIs from Swift, or expose Swift APIs to C++. (Info taken from https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/project-build-setup/#mixing-swift-and-c-using-xcode)