# Calling C++ from Swift - what is the equivalent of std::vector<T>

Tags: swift, objective-c++

I'm calling a C++ function from Swift via a bridging header following [SwiftArchitect's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546879/575530). The signature for the C++ function is this:

```c++
long GrabberInitializeAndProcess(
    unsigned char* pbInPixels,  
    int inStride,
    unsigned char* pbOutPixels, 
    int outStride,
    int width, 
    int height,
    Point mqTopLeft, 
    Size mqSize,
    std::vector<PolylineElement> * pForegroundMarks, 
    std::vector<PolylineElement> * pBackgroundMarks,
    void* pGrabberState );
```

(N.B. `Point`, `Size`, and `PolylineElement` are local C++ structs.) What signature do I use in my Objective-C++ wrapper for `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: `NSArray<PolylineElementWrapperYouCreate*> *`, you're wrapper will be responsible for bridging the two types.

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping the PolylineElement (it's a simple struct of four ints) but I'll put that in as a separate question. Do you want to add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such?

Answer (score 2):

You are using vector as pointer. It's very good when you need use it in Swift.

You can use `void*` instead:

```
long GrabberInitializeAndProcess(
    unsigned char* pbInPixels,  
    int inStride,
    unsigned char* pbOutPixels, 
    int outStride,
    int width, 
    int height,
    Point mqTopLeft, 
    Size mqSize,
    void * pForegroundMarks, 
    void * pBackgroundMarks,
    void* pGrabberState );
```

And perform typecasting in implementation.

Or if you need type safety, you can white:

```
typedef struct _vectorOfPolylineElement *vectorOfPolylineElementPtr;

long GrabberInitializeAndProcess(
    unsigned char* pbInPixels,  
    int inStride,
    unsigned char* pbOutPixels, 
    int outStride,
    int width, 
    int height,
    Point mqTopLeft, 
    Size mqSize,
    vectorOfPolylineElementPtr pForegroundMarks, 
    vectorOfPolylineElementPtr pBackgroundMarks,
    void* pGrabberState );
```

And in implementation:

```
typedef struct _vectorOfPolylineElement
{
    std::vector<PolylineElement> val;
} *vectorOfPolylineElementPtr;
```

And if you actually don't need vector in GrabberInitializeAndProcess, just it elements you can work with memory:

```
long GrabberInitializeAndProcess(
    unsigned char* pbInPixels,  
    int inStride,
    unsigned char* pbOutPixels, 
    int outStride,
    int width, 
    int height,
    Point mqTopLeft, 
    Size mqSize,
    PolylineElement * pForegroundMarks, 
    size_t foregroundMarksCount,
    PolylineElement * pBackgroundMarks,
    size_t backgroundMarksCount,
    void* pGrabberState );
```