# Defining a struct and using it in an NSArray in Objective-C (or Objective-C++)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I'm writing a wrapper to call some C++ from Swift. [I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33526225/575530) that to call a C++ `std::vector` I should use `NSArray`, but the following code fails to compile on the last two function arguments with the error

> Type argument 'PolylineElement' is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type

```objective-c
struct PolylineElement
{
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
};

@interface CPPWrapper : NSObject
- (void) grabberInitializeAndProcessFromPixels: (unsigned char*) pbInPixels
                                   andInStride: (int) inStride
                                  andOutPixels: (unsigned char*) pbOutPixels
                                  andOutStride: (int) outStride
                                      andWidth: (int) width
                                     andHeight: (int) height
                             andMarqueeTopLeft: (Point) mqTopLeft
                            andMarqueeTopRight: (Size) mqSize
                            // Next two lines fail
                            andForegroundMarks: (NSArray<PolylineElement> *) pForegroundMarks
                            andBackgroundMarks: (NSArray<PolylineElement> *) pBackgroundMarks
                               andGrabberState: (void *) pGrabberState;
@end
```

How do I declare an `NSArray` of a struct?

If, following trojanfoe's advice in the comments I make `PolylineElement` into a class thus

```objective-c
@interface PolylineElement : NSObject
{
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
}
@end
```

then I get the error

> Type argument 'PolylineElement' must be a pointer (requires a '*')

But if I fix the function call to use pointers thus

```
@interface CPPWrapper : NSObject
- (void) grabberInitializeAndProcessFromPixels: (unsigned char*) pbInPixels
                                   andInStride: (int) inStride
                                  andOutPixels: (unsigned char*) pbOutPixels
                                  andOutStride: (int) outStride
                                      andWidth: (int) width
                                     andHeight: (int) height
                             andMarqueeTopLeft: (Point) mqTopLeft
                            andMarqueeTopRight: (Size) mqSize
                            andForegroundMarks: (NSArray<PolylineElement *> *) pForegroundMarks
                            andBackgroundMarks: (NSArray<PolylineElement *> *) pBackgroundMarks
                               andGrabberState: (void *) pGrabberState;
@end
```

I do not get compiler issues but each element of the array is now a pointer, not what the C++ is expecting, i.e. there is an extra level of indirection.

Comment: You can wrap `struct`s, however it's probably better to create a custom `NSObject`-subclass object.

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, I've updated the question to take this suggestion into account

Comment: You'll need to show the code that error is referring to.

Comment: There's no error now - I just don't understand how a pointer to an object on the Objective-C side will be interpreted as a struct on the C++ side. I.e. how `(NSArray<PolylineElementClass *> *)` in Objective-C can equate to `(std::vector<PolylineElementStruct> *)`. I'll push on and formulate another question when there's an actual error to grapple with.

Comment: It's not. If you need it in C++ you'll need to write a function to convert NSArray to std::vector by iterating through it.

Comment: Yeah it's not clear exactly what you are doing.  I assume it's swift -> Objective-C++ -> C++?  I would imagine in that case it's better to use `std::vector<PolylineElement>` internally within the Objective-C++ class (and don't expose it via the header file) and then to have methods to add/remove elements from the collection.  Then just give the `vector` straight to the C++.