# How to Importing files from one project to another

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I want to copy some files "Classes" from another project to my current project, but when I run it I get dozen of errors, its seem there are some steps to copying file from one project to another project using Xcode ,

I can make a collection of files "Classes" accessible in my project?

One project is Objective c, the another one seems to be Objective C++

Comment: first right click and click finder see where the file are there

Comment: Language is irrelevant. Drag & drop, really.

Comment: @swiftarchitect , I have tried Drag and drop but I get errors because im new , I have noticed that u have helped alot of peoples in excellent answers and detailed question , can u help me more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Individual Files

**Organize your files**

Place the files you will need at a location that is accessible by the Xcode project. Usually, you place these files is a directory below your Xcode project, but that is absolutely not necessary.

**Drag & drop**

Grab all the files you need and drop them onto your project organizer. You will be prompted with this dialog, to which the settings should look like this *(ensure that your target is selected)*:

[image]

---

## Projects

If you want to include a Cocoa Touch Static Library, in the form of an Xcode project, drag & drop will suffice.

Comment: Brother thank u every thing work fine , now I have two static library one written in c++ and other objective c , when I run project its build successful , but now I want to import one method from objective c++ into my objective c , how ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554229/218152 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32546879/218152. The describe all combinations of C, C++, Swift, Objective-C and Objective-C++

Answer (score 4):

No there are not exactly steps we need to follow. Just make sure all `dependencies` are fulfilled while importing `classes` from other project. Don't forget to click at checkbox `Copy files if needed` so that `Xcode` can make separate copy for your project.
In order to import files in your project click following sequence:

> command + option + A

or you can also add files by

> Xcode -> File -> Add files to "Project Name"