# How to integrate lepton compression in swift code?

Tags: c++, swift, dropbox, image-compression

https://github.com/dropbox/lepton

I want to compress images taken through my camera app using lepton before they're uploaded to my server.

But my front side is completely written in swift and I'm looking for pointers on how to integrate lepton which is written in c++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32541268/2227743